# Cordova Video recorder crash on back phone camera and work on the front one

Tags: vue.js, cordova

I am on a mobile phone project where i try to take a video.
I use Vue.js and cordova

I had added this plugins to cordova:

```
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2"
     cordova-plugin-media-capture
```

I gave the permissions to use the camera because the take a picture parts works just fine. and the video works on the front part.

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn fab @click="takevideo">
      <transition mode="out-in">
        <v-icon v-if="show">mdi-plus</v-icon>
        <v-icon v-else-if="!show" color="green">mdi-check</v-icon>
      </transition>
    </v-btn>
    <div id="preview"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    show: true
  }),
  mounted: function () {
    navigator.camera.showPreview("preview");
  },
  methods: {
    async takevideo() {
      navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(this.captureSuccess, this.captureError);
    },
    captureSuccess: function(mediaFiles) {
        let i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            console.log(mediaFiles[i].fullPath);
        }
        this.show = false
    },
    captureError: function(error) {
        this.show = true
        console.log('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Device is ready the only error I get is this one :

W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Capture.captureVideo blocked the main thread for 91ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

If you have anything that can help me on the CordovaInterface.getThreadPool() that be cool.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Found this when googled... Have your tried this? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/issues/514#issuecomment-544656930 If you are using android device, that is. This is the camera plugin, your issue seems to be the video, but shouldn't be a difference, really.

Comment: Thank you, I will tell you when I found how to resolve the problem with the link.

Comment: @AJT82 it was the quality not a plugin problem in the end

Answer (score 0):

Hello the response was due to the quality too high of the video.
If you put in the options:

```
const options = { quality: 0, limit: YOURNUMBEROFVIDEOTOTAKE}
```

it works well.